# Convolution of two monochromatic waves

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

I was trying to calculate $f * g$ where $f(t) = F(\omega) e^{-i \omega t}$ and $g(t) = G(\omega) e^{-i \omega t}$. I did are the following.

$$(f*g)(t)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} F(\omega)e^{-i \omega (t- \tau)}G(\omega)e^{-i \omega \tau} d\tau=F(\omega)G(\omega)e^{( \omega t)}\int^\infty_{-\infty}d\tau=\infty$$

Is it correct? I was expecting something like

$$(f * g) (t) = F(\omega)G(\omega)e^{( \omega t)}$$

Comment: You'd better write $f(t)=F(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}$ to make it clear that $t$ is the variable (and $\omega$ is constant).

Comment: done, do you think it is correct?

Comment: If we look at the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g,$ then these are $\hat f(\tau)=F(\omega) \delta(\tau-\omega)$ and similar for $g$. The Fourier transform of a convolution is a product, so we get $\delta(\tau-\omega)\delta(\tau-\omega)$ which, if we shall give it a value, is infinite. So yes, your result seems correct.